Spring Batch Stop/Start Master Job
I want to run Spring Batch v4 in a multi-JVM instance (each instance on a different machine) and use SQS to distribute the work from master to the worker JVMs (Remote Partitioning) .
Once the master hands off the partitions to the channel (for the workers), I am planning to shutdown the master step so it won't consume resources (so it's not a long-running task). Once the job is completed, I will then restart the master to finish the job.
Is my approach correct? What are the possible pitfalls?

That approach is not correct. And this really is not where you should be looking for optimisations. The  manager is responsible for gathering replies from workers and reconciling their statuses, so it has to be up until workers are done (either successfully or with a failure).

Hi @Mahmoud, thanks for the response. Just a bit more background

"The manager is responsible for gathering replies from workers and reconciling their statuses, so it has to be up until workers are done (either successfully or with a failure)"


We want to run the master instance in AWS lambda, and the job might take more than 15 mins.

....and 2. We are letting the worker instance save the state / status to the jobRepositoryDb anyway,
so why not turn off the master and just resume it once the workers are completed with the partitions?

Everything is possible. Give it a try, but do not expect any guarantee from spring batch if you use it in a way that it was not designed for.
